# Format exception from a textbox

Tags: c#, exception, format

I've 2 textboxes, out from which I try to collect data.
I'am looping trough them, but when the program is about to collect data from them and they dont have any value, they are empty, I get a format exception saying: "Input string was not in a correct format."

```
if (this.Controls["txt_db0" + count].Text != null)
 {
   //if the value in the textbox is not null
   int db = int.Parse((this.Controls["txt_db0" + count].Text));
   //set my "db" integer to the value of the textbox.
 }
```

I put the if statement there to filter out if there is no value in them, even tho I get the format exception, so I must be doing something wrong.

Comment: Put a breakpoint on `int db = ...` and check the value of `this.Controls["txt_db0" + count].Text`.

Comment: Well depends on what you have found while debugging this :)

Comment: `So what format could it be in the textbox that the compiler cant Parse/Convert to Int?` I don't know, what *could* it be? *YOU* need to step through your code and find out what kind of values `int.Parse` is failing on. You'll probably answer your own question in the process, and if not, provide some information that's necessary for anybody to answer this question at all.

Comment: It's only giving me an exception when there is no value in at least one of the textboxes at all.

Comment: Then you could probably check if the `.Text.Lenght > 0` instead of `!= null`

Comment: .Text.Lenght > 0 does not throws the exception anymore thanks! Yet I still dont understand why !=null didnt work.

Answer (score 1):

to check your work you can do this

```
int testInt;
if (int.TryParse(this.Controls["txt_db0" + count].Text,out testInt))
{
  //if the value in the textbox is not null
  int db = testInt;
  //set my "db" integer to the value of the textbox.
}
else
  MessageBox.Show(this.Controls["txt_db0" + count].Text + "  Not an Int");
```

Comment: The Text-property of controls (in the .NET-framework) are never null.

Answer (score 0):

int.Parse will throw an exception if:

- The input string contains letters, or other special characters that cannot be recognized as a number.
- The input string is an empty string.

If you are sure your input strings only contain digits, check if your string is empty first before converting:

```
string input = this.Controls["txt_db0" + count].Text;
int db = input == "" ? 0 : int.Parse(input);
```

or you could use:

```
int db;
if (!int.TryParse(this.Controls["txt_db0" + count].Text, out db))
     // Do something else.
```